# express runs on two ports even when port is specified

Tags: javascript, express, server

I use `app.listen(PORTNO)` for running my express app.

It runs on `127.0.0.1:PORTNO` but also on `127.0.0.1:3000`

3000 is the default port no on which express runs out of box.

Why this unexpected behaviour?

I have tried setting the env variable to production and also using `http.createServer(app).listen(PORTNO);`

I am generating my express app files using `express-generator`.

I am on a windows machine if its relevant

UPDATE:
I start the server using `npm start` which runs `bin\www`, and it specifies the port to run the server.
But this does not explains the binding to two port :the one specified in `app.js` and the other in `bin\www` for the same app and the app being accessible from both of them.

Can you explain the why?

Comment: Can you provide some more details for instance the code where you are creating the server. Please make sure all the previous instances are killed before you start a new instance just to be sure.

Comment: Just updated the question. The code is generated one with express-generator skelton code only with minor modification to set the port.Also I have killed all the instance and tried

Comment: `express-generator` does not put `app.listen()` in `app.js`, so it's something that was added afterwards.

Comment: What's the value of `PORTNO`?

Comment: @robertklep yes that is one way for setting the port no. i added

Comment: @HageYaapa PORTNO is a valid port no. I use 8079

Answer (score 0):

You should start your server using node server.js(filename). Try this if it helps since when you start it with npm it will get default configurations. And Moreover npm command is used to install the node modules(mostly) rather than running the server.

Comment: `node app.js` exits without running the server. I have wondered why it happens, could you explain why?

Comment: It can happen since the port your trying to run is already running the same instance of app.js. or the port is already binded with some application. So now you know that your app.js does not work. Kill all the instances again and then try again to run node app.js. That might help !

Comment: `node app.js` won't do anything since it is a module. If you look at the source code of `bin\www`, you will see that `app.js` is being loaded in it, and the `listen` function is called in `bin\www`.

Comment: @HageYaapa that makes sense now that I got time to look into the code of bin\www.
It also means that two `http` objects are being created one in `app.js` other in `bin\www` therefore I am able to access the app from two different ports. 
I never looked into the code of bin\www thinking that it is auto generated all the time like it happens in Java